# match dates using python regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I want to match dates that have the following format:

2010-08-27, 
2010/08/27

Right now I am not very particular about the date being actually feasible, but just that it is in the correct format.

please tell the regular expression for this.

Thanks

Comment: This is pretty basic. Have you tried anything on your own?

Comment: Do you only want to check the format or convert it?  If you want also conversion, please have a look at 'time.strptime' - which does not need any regular expression.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can use the `datetime` module to parse dates:

```
import datetime

print datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-08-27', '%Y-%m-%d')
print datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-15-27', '%Y-%m-%d')
```

output:

```
2010-08-27 00:00:00
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./x.py", line 6, in <module>
    print datetime.datetime.strptime('2010-15-27', '%Y-%m-%d')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 325, in _strptime
    (data_string, format))
ValueError: time data '2010-15-27' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'
```

So catching `ValueError` will tell you if the date matches:

```
def valid_date(datestring):
    try:
        datetime.datetime.strptime(datestring, '%Y-%m-%d')
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False
```

To allow for various formats you could either test for all possibilities, or use `re` to parse out the fields first:

```
import datetime
import re

def valid_date(datestring):
        try:
                mat=re.match('(\d{2})[/.-](\d{2})[/.-](\d{4})$', datestring)
                if mat is not None:
                        datetime.datetime(*(map(int, mat.groups()[-1::-1])))
                        return True
        except ValueError:
                pass
        return False
```

Comment: i want to match DD/MM/YYYY ,DD-MM-YYYY pattern dates using Regular expression and substitute such strings with 'DATE' string. using python

Comment: Well you could just test it again all possible variants in your function, or extract the digits with a regular expression. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can use this code:

```
import re

# regular expression to match dates in format: 2010-08-27 and 2010/08/27 
# date_reg_exp = re.compile('(\d+[-/]\d+[-/]\d+)')
```

**updated regular expression below:**

```
# regular expression to match dates in format: 2010-08-27 and 2010/08/27
# and with mixed separators 2010/08-27
# date_reg_exp = re.compile('\d{4}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2}')

# if separators should not be mixed use backreference:
date_reg_exp = re.compile('\d{4}(?P<sep>[-/])\d{2}(?P=sep)\d{2}')

# a string to test the regular expression above
test_str= """
     fsf2010/08/27sdfsdfsd
     dsf sfds f2010/08/26 fsdf 
     asdsds 2009-02-02 afdf
     """
# finds all the matches of the regular expression and
# returns a list containing them
matches_list=date_reg_exp.findall(test_str)

# iterates the matching list and prints all the matches
for match in matches_list:
  print match
```

Comment: ok, I think the hochl's answer is the best as it uses `datetime` that can validate a date. Then if you wan to use a regular expression to do this, it is better to use this provided by jamylak: `"\d{4}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2}"` as it also checks that length of year string is 4 characters and of day and month is exactly 2 characters. :)

Comment: please tell me how to substitue new pattern in matching strings

Comment: You given great answer,can u tell how to match time formats  00:08

Comment: Yes, you can use this regular expression: `time_reg_exp = re.compile('(\d{2}:\d{2})')` and the whole will be similar to my answer. If you wish vote my question please! :)

Comment: one should mention that the provided regex also matches dates with mixed separators such as '2010/08-27'.

Answer (score 7):

Use the `datetime` module. Here is a regex for the sake of knowledge although you shouldn't use it:

```
r'\d{4}[-/]\d{2}[-/]\d{2}'
```

Answer (score 2):

dateutil package has a quite smart dates parser. It parses a wide range of dateformats. 
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-dateutil

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
test_str= '''
     fsf2010/08/27sdfsdfsd
     dsf sfds f2010/08/26 fsdf 
     asdsds 2009-02-02 afdf
     '''

date_regex = re.compile('\d{4}[/.-]\d{2}[/.-]\d{2}')    
  
for match in date_regex.findall(test_str):
    print(match)
```

output:

```
2010/08/27
2010/08/26
2009-02-02
```