# Match date using python regular expression

Tags: python

How can i match the following dates with python regular expression in one statement, dates are:

```
  11/12/98
   0/0/0
  25/02/1977
```

The following doesnt work for 0/0/0

```
 p_date = re.compile(r'(\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4})')
```

Comment: Do you want to match real dates, or just sequences of digits and slashes? (Example: `72/42/3456` is not a date).

Comment: also rel: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9978534/989121

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to fix the numbers of numbers that you're expecting.

```
p_date = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,4})')
```

Then, if you want to get the individual numbers in groups,

```
p_date = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2})[/-](\d{1,2})[/-](\d{1,4})')
```

Comment: 0/0/0 is still not matching Can i do this .. p_date = re.compile(r'(\d{1,2})[/-](\d{1,2})[/-](\d{1,2,4})')

Comment: This would not pass 0/0/0 I suppose, it needs to be 1,4 for year as well.

Comment: @Rajeev: yes it is. If you can't get it to match, your code is wrong elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be incorrect regex to check for this pattern.

```
'(\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4}[/-]\d{2,4})'
```

as it has condition of 2 to 4 characters for month,day,and year fields,
which would obviously not match something like  `0/0/0`

Correct regex would be :

```
'(\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,2}[/-]\d{1,4})'  # for month,day,year  or day,month,year
                                   # whatever your formate is
```

Answer (score 0):

`\d{2,4}` means a number that is at least 2 digit, and 4 the most. You can try `\d{1,2}` or `\d{1,4}` to match the desired number of digits.