# how to fetch a set number of characters after substring

Tags: python, string, date, substring

I have a table column of sentences and each sentence has a date that I want to get, all  of the sentences are a bit different but the dates all come after "the due date is"

example:

"text text text the due date is 04/26/2017 text text text text"

how can I fetch only the dates that comes immediately after "due date is" I am wondering if I can fetch the 10 characters that comes after "due date is" since the dates are all 10 characters long

Comment: Yes you can do that assuming all of your data is very well-formatted. If you need to deal with data that is a lot less reliable, consider using regular expressions.

Comment: You may find [this answer for Regular Expressions for dates in `Python`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978534/match-dates-using-python-regular-expressions#answer-9978804) useful.

Comment: to fetch the 10 characters that come after "due date is", you can split strings on a delimiter, using string "due date is" as the delimiter, grab the second-half of the splitted result, and slice the first 10 characters after the first space `[1:10]`...so altogether: `print mystring.split("due date is",1)[1][1:11]` may work

Comment: (typo in my last comment `[1:10]` should be `[1:11]`), I based the code off of this answer [Get a string after a specific substring](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572362/get-a-string-after-a-specific-substring)