# python efficient way to validate date

Tags: python, validation, datetime

I have a large file with the date in %m%d%Y format i.e 12012013 for 12th jan 2013.

I have to perform 2 things:

1) validate the date
2) store it in a list in sorted chronological format

for validation:

```
        try:
            parsedDate = datetime.strptime(date, '%m%d%Y')
            return parsedDate
        except:
            return None'
```

using DateTime take a lot of time to parse the date. Since the format is mmddyyyy, can I validate it without using datetime efficiently?

2) For chronological order: I dont want to convert it to datetime and then sort it, is there a way I can use string to sort it. I have check a lot of answers, but almost all of them assumes that you have a list and then sort it.

I want to insert it in a sorted format?

Comment: Do you want to return the validated date as a string or a datetime object? If conversion is not a necessity, just split your string and do an integer bounds check.

Comment: I was planning to do the same but then I'll have to consider leap year cases,  cases where days in a month are 31,30 and all other variations which I want to avoid. moreover I also want to sort the date

Comment: How do you know it is datetime that's slowing you down?

Answer (score 0):

1. datetime module is pretty good, still if you want any other option you can validate as reg expression, check: [match dates using python regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978534/match-dates-using-python-regular-expressions).
2. To sort the date without converting to datetime. Just convert it into format yyyymmdd then do string sort or just create a empty list then append the string to the the correct position based on value greater or lesser.

Would request you to try it yourself :)

Comment: sorting into yyyymmdd should work. Thanks for that!. I'll check the regex part!

Answer (score 0):

If the format is `%m%d%Y`, the most efficient is using a RegEx (there are some profiling about that).

For instance:

```
import re
import datetime

match_date = re.compile(r'(\d{2})(\d{2})(\d{4})$').match

text = '12012013'
mo = match_date(text)

if mo:
    date = datetime.date(int(mo.group(3)), int(mo.group(1)), int(mo.group(2)))
    print(date)
    # -> 2013-12-01
```

That way, the RegEx will do the first level of filtering and the `date` constructor the second (with an exception). Of course, you can improve your RegEx, this one is trivial for the demo.

If you know in advance that your dates are all valid you can avoid the conversion to `date` and use the `tuple` (year, month, day) for sorting, instead of using `date`.