# Regular Expression (regex) Search for 'Mmm dd hh:mm:ss' Pattern and Group using Python 3.6

Tags: python, regex, datetime

Hi I am writing a `regex` program to search for a pattern **`Mmm dd hh:mm:ss`** in the given sentence. For example I want to identify if a pattern such as **Mmm dd hh:mm:ss** is present in the given sentence ( for example, Aug  03 50:42:08 is the optimistic time to start the work). I went through [many stack overflow questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9978534/7245145) that fall under this topic. But still I am not able to figure out the exact `regex pattern (template)` to identify if `Mmm dd hh:mm:ss` is present in the given sentence?

**Edit 1:**

So once this pattern is identified, what should be done to group those sentences which matched the pattern into one group and the sentences which did not match the pattern into another group?

The code developed so far is below:

```
regexp = re.compile('[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s\d)\s\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+')
if regexp.search('we shall meet on Jun 26 10:45:09'):
    print('matched')
```

**Output:**

```
>>> matched
```

Comment: Do you really need regex? Why not just attempt conversion with a format string?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below expression will not match time with 3 digits and matches time with 1 digit also

1. Doesn't match Jun 10 14:100:40
2. Doesn't match Jun 100 14:10:40
3. Matches month June or Jun ( if don't want to accept June replace 4 with 3

   `re.findall(r'\b\w{1,4} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}',s)`

To group matched and unmacthed patterns

```
import re
s = "We will meet on June 10 14:10:40"
pattern = r'\b\w{1,4} \d{1,2} \d{1,2}:\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}'
match = re.search(pattern, s)
print s[:match.start()]
print match.group()
```

Comment: @SteffiKeranRaniJ : Check if the extra code solves your problem

Answer (score 1):

This regex will follow that pattern but won't validate that months are correct.

```
^[A-Z][a-z]{2} \d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d$
```

Answer (score 1):

Given a string, you can try this:

```
import re
s = "We will meet on Jun 10 4:12:40" 
date = re.findall('[a-zA-Z]+(?=\s\d)\s\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+', s)[0]
```

Output:

```
'Jun 10 4:12:40'
```

Answer (score 1):

Below regex will validate month as well:

```
(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d\d \d\d:\d\d:\d\d
```

Answer (score 1):

I think [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/e8xqBG/1) will match the format in 24h notation:

`^(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\s(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])\s([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$`

- From the beginning of the string `^`
- Match the months `(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)`
- Match a whitespace `\s`
- Match the days `(0?[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])`
- Match a whitespace `\s`
- Match the hours in 24h notations `([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3])`
- Match a semi colon `:`
- Match the minutes `[0-5][0-9]`
- Match a semi colon `:`
- Match the seconds `[0-5][0-9]`
- Match the end of the line `$`

**Note**: this does note take care of edge cases like Jun 31 23:45:09

Answer (score 0):

This Question is a bit older, but because I couldn't find anything that covered **all** edge cases, here it is:
(Beware that this regex is for matching, so remove the caret and dollar sign for a searching regex)

This regex makes it impossible to do edge cases, every time that is validated, is a legitimate time.

###### Regex:

`^((Jan|Mar|May|Jul|Aug|Oct|Dec) (?!00|3[2-9])[0-3]\d|(Apr|Jun|Sep|Nov) (0[1-9]|[12]\d|30)|Feb (?!00)[0-2]\d) (?!2[4-9])[0-2]\d:[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d$`

###### Valid examples:

- Jun 03 00:00:00
- Sep 30 15:19:27
- Feb 28 23:18:41
- Dec 31 20:03:51

###### Invalid examples:

- Feb 30 00:00:00 (February only has 29 days)
- Dec 32 23:26:33 (December only has 31 days)
- Sep 00 12:39:51 (Cannot be day zero)
- Apr 10 24:36:11 (Cannot be more than 23 hours
- May 12 22:60:43 (Cannot be more than 59 seconds)

###### Disclaimer:

Its probably bad to do this as a regex, especially considering the size of the regex