# Stripping Dates from Strings in Python by Converting Regex to 'Str'

Tags: python, regex, string, python-3.x, replace

I am looking to strip dates out of a list of longer strings, each of which, may or may not, contain a date. An example of one such string might be:

```
"Jane Doe 76554334 12/15/2017 - 8:35 pm 700945 - SDFTRD $550.95"
```

I have built a method which is returning an error:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'match_object'
```

My aim has been to look for regex matches on `(\d+/\d+/\d+)` and then convert that match to a string so that it can be used with `.replace()`. I cannot seem to solve this using `match_object`.

Here is my method:

```
def replace_match(string):
    match=re.search(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)',string)
    if match:
        match=re.match(r'(\d+/\d+/\d+)',string).match_object.group(0)
        print("match = " + match)
        string = string.replace(match, "")
    else:
        print("no match found")
    return string
```

I am using Python 3.6.3

Comment: You should found others means to do that in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978534/match-dates-using-python-regular-expressions) with try-catch.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `re.sub`:

```
import re
s = "Jane Doe 76554334 12/15/2017 - 8:35 pm 700945 - SDFTRD $550.95"
new_s = re.sub('\d+\/\d+\/\d+', '', s)
```

Output:

```
'Jane Doe 76554334  - 8:35 pm 700945 - SDFTRD $550.95'
```

Edit, removing the timestamp:

```
import re
s = "Jane Doe 76554334 12/15/2017 - 8:35 pm 700945 - SDFTRD $550.95"
new_s = re.sub('\d+\/\d+\/\d+|\d+:\d+(?=\spm)|\d+:\d+(?=\sam)', '', s)
```

Output:

```
'Jane Doe 76554334  -  pm 700945 - SDFTRD $550.95'
```

Explanation for timestamp removal regex:

`\d+:\d+`: matches hour then minutes
`(?=\sam)`: is a positive lookahead, which means that `\d+:\d+` will not register a match unless the matched characters are followed by a space and then `am`, designating that it is indeed a time stamp.

`\d+:\d+(?=\spm)` does the same as above except that it is checking if the time match is preceded by pm, accounting for both time conventions.

Comment: That worked! I'm curious though, I'm used to using regex in the format of ```r'(\d+\/\d+\/\d+)'```. Just curious if you knew why the ```r()``` was not necessary in this instance.

Comment: @HMLDude `r`, or raw string, enables the interpreter to immediately treat any `"\"`s as a special character in the escape sequence, or literally. In normal strings, `"\"` is considered as `"\"` unless used as an escape character. In the case of regex in Python, the interpreter will still evaluate `"\"` as an escape character regardless of whether it was passed as a raw string.

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding redundant escaping, use `'\d+/\d+/\d+'`. In Python regex patterns, `/` is never special.

Comment: I have been messing around with this quite a bit since this answer was posted, including using @WiktorStribiżew's suggestion of removing unnecessary slashes. Curious what you guys would suggest for removing the timestamp as in ```8:35``` in the example above.

Comment: @Ajax1234 that did it. Trying to understand why the timestamp is so much more complicated an expression as compared to the date.

Comment: @HMLDude please see my recent edit for an explanation of the timezone regex.