# Spacy not Recognizing Date Properly

Tags: python, machine-learning, nlp

```
nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_md')
text =" Activity Date: 12/18/2019 06:00:00AM CST "
doc  = nlp(text)
for entity in doc.ents:
    print(entity.label_+" "+ entity.text)
```

Here spacy is not able to extract date time. I also tried 'en' and 'en_core_web_lg'.

I also encounter a situation when we change the format of the date to (DD/MM/YYYY).It recognizes the date .

```
text = " 18/12/2019"
doc  = nlp(text)
for entity in doc.ents:
    print(entity.label_+" "+ entity.text)
```

Has anyone encountered the same Problem.

Answer (score 3):

Spacy employs probabilistic models to try and identify Named Entities in Natural Language. This means that it gives probabilities that Named Entities are of a certain type (such as a date, a person or an organisation).

You can influence the probability that a Date is recognized correctly in two ways:
Make sure more contextual clues are included in the text surrounding the date, i.e.:
`The activity occurred on 12/18/2019 at 06:00:00AM CST`

Or, alternatively, you can train the Spacy probabilistic model on your dataset, feeding it where it needs to recognize dates. More info here:
https://spacy.io/usage/training

However, maybe your use-case is better suited for Regex approaches or even datetime imports to date recognition? This has been done before, check for example:
[match dates using python regular expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9978534/match-dates-using-python-regular-expressions)

Answer (score 2):

For my particular use case  I resolved it by using the  **dateparser**.
You can check it our here [Dateparser](https://pypi.org/project/dateparser/)